# How To Sort the JSON response in Ascending which is being fetched from an Endpoint in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is my JSON request body to be sent for the request endpoint

```
    {
        "id": "191", 
        "order":"ASC" 
    }
```

```
    HttpPost request1 = new HttpPost("/2.0/clusters/events");
    Map< String, Object >jsonValues = new HashMap< String, Object >();
    jsonValues.put("id", s);

    //fetching id from another API and for each id fetching the events.

    JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(jsonValues);
    request1.addHeader("Authorization",bearerToken);
    request1.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request1.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonO.toString(), "UTF8");
    request1.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(request1);
    String json1 = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
    event= new JSONObject(json1);
    JSONArray arrays=event.getJSONArray("events");

    List<JSONObject> json_Values = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int k=0;k< arrays.length();k++){
    json_Values.add(arrays.getJSONObject(k));
    JSONObject ids = arrays.getJSONObject(k);
    String id=clusterids.get("id").toString();
    String time=clusterids.get("timestamp").toString(); 
    String type=clusterids.get("type").toString(); 
    System.out.println("id:" + id + "\t" + "Time:" + time + "\t" + "Type:" + type + "\n");

    Collections.sort(json_Values, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "timestamp";
    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
    Object valA = new Object().toString();
    Object valB = new Object().toString();
    valA =a.get(KEY_NAME);
    valB = b.get(KEY_NAME);
    return ( (String) valA).compareTo(  (String) valB);
    }
    });
    JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Sorted array:"+sortedJsonArray.put(jsonValues.get(i)));
    }
    }
    System.out.println("EVENTS:"+arrays);
    }
    return event;
    }
```

Here I am comparing the two timestamp to fetch sorted response,but I am facing some exceptions like

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to 
    java.lang.String
    at testdatabricks.testdatabricks.Events$1.compare(Events.java:170)
    at testdatabricks.testdatabricks.Events$1.compare(Events.java:1)
```

Can I send json body to sort the values? How to pass that? Help me to find this out.

Comment: Why are you trying to sort the JSON objects themselves? Simply create a POJO and then get a `Comparator` for it and then simply user `Collections.sort(<your-array-of-POJO-objects>, <your-Comparator>);`

Comment: Use a JSON handling library like FasterXML Jackson or Google GSON to serialize and deserialize JSON

Comment: This is not the API which have been written by me,I am hitting the endpoint where I need to sort the JSONObjects itself while fetching the response.
Here I cant create a POJO class i think

Comment: Why would you require to sort the `JSONObjects` themselves? I'm assuming you are getting a `List` of  `JSONObjects` like the one you have mentioned as an example. In that case, you can simply create a POJO and proceed with my mentioned solution.

Comment: Do you know is there any way to order the response in ASC by sending it in the body itself ,than using comparison after fetching it.

Comment: What you are basically saying is that the endpoint should send ordered data, right?

Comment: yes I need sorted data from that end point

Comment: Is it possible for you to get the data in a sorted way from the endpoint itself? Because that's how it should be like. The backend should send you the data in a sorted way itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to make a string comparison? Anyway if so then your compare method is somewhat wrong and should more look like:

```
    Collections.sort(json_Values, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "timestamp";
        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
            String valA = a.get(KEY_NAME).toString();
            String valB = b.get(KEY_NAME).toString();
            return valA.compareTo(valB);
        }
    });
```

just because you initialise valA as a String Object (`Object valA = new Object().toString();`) does not mean that val stays a String Object. When you do `valA =a.get(KEY_NAME);` this will not cast this to a String but it stays in the type that `a.get(KEY_NAME)` had before (it is exactly the same object - seemingly sometimes of type Long). But String is a nice thing - as basically all Objects that you likely encounter in a JSON have meaningful `toString()` implementations. So you can use that to convert everything to String and make your String comparison.
But if you timestamp is always a Long  your better of with a Long-comparison:

```
    Collections.sort(json_Values, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "timestamp";
        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
            Long valA = (Long)a.get(KEY_NAME);
            Long valB = (Long)b.get(KEY_NAME);
            return valA.compareTo(valB);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your bug is here from what I can make out of the stack trace:

```
public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
    Object valA = new Object().toString();
    Object valB = new Object().toString();
    valA =a.get(KEY_NAME);
    valB = b.get(KEY_NAME);
    return ( (String) valA).compareTo(  (String) valB);
    }
```

your `valA` and `valB` are `Long` types. And that's okay because timestamps are in long format. You need to use `Long` instead of `String`. And this is how you do it:

```
Long valA = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(a.get(KEY_NAME)));
```

Then simply `return valA.compareTo(valB);`